# Cassandra MessagingService ServerSocket thread hangs during decommission

Tags: java, sockets, cassandra, websphere, ibm-jvm

I'm running embedded Cassandra 1.2.18 within an application deployed on Websphere Application Server 8.5.0, with Java 1.6, JVM IBM J9 2.6 (shipped with the appserver). It starts up fine, and is perfectly usable. It's the only node in the Cassandra cluster.

However, when I try to decommission the node, Cassandra gets as far as trying to shutdown its MessagingService, and then hangs. Debugging, I can see that it's trying to close a ServerSocket that it's opened, listening to the servers own ip, port 7000 (which Cassandra uses for inter-node communication).

This stops Cassandra from shutting down correctly, and even stops the entire server from being gracefully shutdown. I realise it's probably a very specific situation, but has anyone experienced something similar with Cassandra / on Websphere before, or can anyone with more ServerSocket experience than me suggest what is happening?